# The point of Yii2 environments folder

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am trying to work what the point of the environments folder is.

Originally I had the idea that you could point the webserver to the different `dev` and `prod` folders in the `environment` folder but after reading up a bit I realise this is not the case.

In Yii 1 you would solve this by just having multiple `index.php`'s i.e.:

- `index.php`
- `index-local.php`

So the question is what benefit does this new environment structure actually give me over the old way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found environments very useful in allowing me to keep a common code base for multiple client projects (based on Yii App Advanced) and setting up a different environment for each specific client, keeping their custom code private and separate.

To do this I store the environments folder in a separate git repo from the rest of the code and pull down the relevant folder on a client/project basis.

This lets me use a base common code for all projects and add/override any file for a specific client or project whilst still allowing separate dev/prod config settings. If the client uses other developers too, they are also catered for. In this way, only common code I choose will be shared amongst clients and custom code will be kept private.

I've also moved the composer.json file into the environments folder so I can pull in different extensions per client/project keeping those private too.

That init command can be a very powerful tool and you don't have to limit yourself to the template provided by the core developers.

If you don't need environments, then don't use them, but I assure you some people will find it very useful.

Comment: I have too, even on a single client actually found this more useful, i.e. no special server config to fence off other index files actually and things like that

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 documentation in WIP, but you should read this :

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/apps-advanced.md#configuration-and-environments

You need to use yii `init` command to switch between these environments.

**EDIT** :

This new environment feature is more than just use different config file. You can use different folder structure, different entry script...etc

Personnaly I won't use this feature, I don't need it (I will use a different entry script as with Yii 1), but I think this is not useless.

Comment: That's not my quesiton. I know how to use environments already

Comment: I don't have an answer to my question nor can I find a reasonable epxlanation

Comment: Updated, but not with a "reasonable explanation" :)

Comment: You have the same sentiment as me whereby I feel like sticking with Yii1 way of doing it. In fact I think I can see a drawback to the envo setup, it can nly run one envo at a time. What if you have the same code base that goes to two different dbs, one work and one live? Hmmm more I think about this more it seems that the envo part of Yii was not thought out very well if I am honest

Comment: You are right. And I don't think Yii 2 will bring a lot of interesting new features (except namespaces and composer packaging). It will still stay a very good mvc framework (but Laravel is quite good too).

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't get the real purpose of environments introduced in Yii2.

I'll try to explain what was the main purpose of adding environments to yii from the developers point of view on an example and hope you will really appreciate its usefulness.

Let's suppose for a moment that you are a team of developers (e.g. 5-7 person) working on mid-to-large project implemented in Yii. To effectively work on that project your team decides to use some CVS or SVN (e.g. GIT) and keep all the files of the project in repository in cloud for the whole team. That's de facto standard while working on mid-to-large projects in teams and nobody will resist that it's the only comfortable and easy way.

Ok, now let's suppose you use Yii 1.x or Yii2 with the approach of different entry scripts to differentiate between local (development) and production environments to connect to db or set some other environment specific configs. Everything is ok and working. But suppose your team members implemented something new on the project and you check out repository to work on updated version and you suddenly find out that your local config file (in this case entry script with config) is overwritten with other team member's file who pulled the changes to repository (because each of you is using your local machine db with other database name or OS, or config, or simply because your team uses one local development server db, but you are on vacation and can't use anything except your local machine).

So generally Yii2 environment adds more flexibility for using different environments each with it's own specific configurations while using also general (common) configs when working in teams on mid-to-large projects hence why the example in guide is given on advanced app project.

Surely you can overcome everything stated above with some solutions or .gitignore which is used by default to overcome the problem stated in Yii2 with environments. But:

1. Why bother if everything is already done?

and

1. It was just one little example of usefulness of Yii2 environments. More depends on the project and your imagination.

Overall Yii2 is great product. Not only it adds many new features to already great framework, but it also is more robust and flexible than Yii 1.x (despite the fact that Yii 1.x was already very robust).

As for Laravel or any other PHP framework, it really depends... Everyone will find his/her own favorite.

Comment: It is only already done because Yii has added the gitignore, it is not an inheritant benefit of using Yii2 envos. I have been trying to find its usefulness in a project of about 200 tables and 10 devs but as of yet the local entry and config file still rules due to the fact that it doesn't clutter up the workspace.

Comment: I really don't get the ease of your approach. If using other entry file for dev environment and to achieve the same as with environments, you must also use local specific `.htaccess` to overwrite remove local entry script for example. And again this was another example. I can bring many-many more examples that new approach is better and easier to use. Your argument is that you cannot use two environments concurrently (without init), but if you need to use two environments at a time, than you're doing something wrong. There is always strong distinction between environments (dev, prod, test ...)

Comment: No I have a staging process whereby the web server of the local envo is pointing to the index-local.php

Comment: @Sammaye Another one for you. Every big project is involving. And there were migrations in Yii 1.x and there are migrations in Yii 2.x and they are used extensively in such projects. With entry script approach, what about environment specific migrations? It is common practice to have environment specific migrations.

Comment: How would having a file of a different name help here? If you are required to have your entry script as index.php that sounds like bad coding

Comment: @Sammaye Good point you mentioned. Your local web server is pointing to index-local.php and every dev must know it in your team and every dev must configure every instance of local server (be it work computer, home computer). And you think it's right approach? And what about new dev in your team, or if suddenly someone in team decides or by mistake renames index-local.php in common GIT repository (ofcourse if it is in repo).

Comment: We have a git for storing each staging configuration file, it is the only truly logical way in a large project, this way when you go to setup a computer to just copy the file form the webbrowser or pull it down and you have it

Comment: @Sammaye I didn't understand your comment about entry script. But there must be one entry script always and you can simply manipulate every other thing by changing configs (local, prod...) and changing one constant or simply using init script for that.

Comment: No one should ever touch the index-local.php, if that is the case then what sotps them from renaming index.php and commiting that if they are like that?

Comment: I suspect that we can argue infinitely and the comments is not appropriate place for that. So I will conclude that it's more of a preference issue. Our team found the environments concept in Yii 2.x more easy and flexible for the use in mid-to-large projects, while for smaller projects there are countless approaches without all the hassle with configs or entry scripts.

Comment: It does seem like a specific preference/setup thing

Answer (score 0):

For those who are tired of copying files around, I created a useful script that you can run in background to keep the files in sync on your dev environment:

File sync-env-files.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

ENVIRONMENT_DIR="/var/www/example.com/environments/dev/"
DIR="/var/www/example.com/"

while [ true ]; do
    for envFile in `find $ENVIRONMENT_DIR -type f`
    do
        file=${envFile/$ENVIRONMENT_DIR/$DIR}
        if [ `stat -c "%Y" $file` -gt `stat -c "%Y" $envFile` ]; then
            #echo "copying modified file $file to $envFile"
            /bin/cp -f $file $envFile
        fi
    done
    sleep 2
done
```

Then run the script in background or add to cron with flock

```
nohup server/sync-env-files.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to mention in addition to @AngelCoding, since this question still gets seen, that I use the `environments` folder lots now and definitely see the point of it.

The very first things I do in any open source project is create one project for the code base on GitHub and then another, private, one on Bitbucket for the configuration, in other words the `environments` folder.

Having this folder has made it a lot easier for me to separate my configuration into a private repository.

So the `environments` folder has a lot of uses and really helps to separate configuration for easier usage even if it does not seem like it initially.

Comment: How and when are you guys telling Yii to switch environment? I know how to run the command, and know what it does, and what it is for. If we switch environment locally, the git repo is out of sync. So we would have to add/commit, then push to server. That seems like un-necessary clogging of commit records. So my assumption is it would be best to do it on the server. Now I could ssh in and run yii init. I assume you guys are automating it. Are you using git to execute yii init after you push? Or are you using a hook in your hosting? (ie OpenShift allows hooks in your config to run commands)..

Comment: @WadeShuler the git repo would be out of synch no matter what command you run it will always create files you should not upload to git. Any and all files created by the init command should not be in git. We have it as part of a command which updates our repo on the server side.